# Responsive top nav not responding properly

Tags: html, css

I'm not even sure if the question title makes sense. Basically, I have a topnav that is responsive and it is working the way I want it except for at a certain point between the media breakpoints. The problem is that the name of the person in the link is too long, so it makes that tab much bigger when the screen is minimized. Any help is much appreciated!

I tried changing all px to % but it didn't fix the issue. I tried creating a new class for that specific tab as well, but it quickly became too cluttered and didn't give me the results I was hoping for anyways. I also tried adding css in the  for that specific tab. I'm not sure if this is a padding  problem or a font-size problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkpBQ.jpg

```
//default topnav CSS//

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 14px;
  border: none;
  float: left;
  font-size: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none; 
  width: 25%;
  outline: 0;
}

//media breakpoint for tablet//

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 90%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none; 
  outline: 0;
}
```

I don't want the formatting to be out of line. I want everything in-line until the media breakpoint but that isn't happening.

Comment: What behavior do you want at that break point? You could hide overflow, or text-wrap which it looks like it's doing. But if your content exceeds it's container width, you need to specify the behavior. overflow: hidden, word-wrap: break-word or some other behavior.

Comment: I've come across the same issue several times. Usually I resolve it by making the font smaller, but not on an individual name, rather as a class that works for all the names. (You could also consider reducing the name 'Marcel' to just his initial 'M'?)

Comment: Brant, the break point is doing what I want it to do. But when I minimize the page, just before the break point, the tab "marcel louis-jacques" is a lot bigger than all the other ones and i'm not sure why. So when my browser is in full screen it looks great, when I minimize it it looks good, but when I go to minimize it further there is a specific point at which it becomes out of line, just before it hits the break point. I put an imgur link so you should be able to see what's happening.

Comment: Inputforcolor, yeah I was worried that it would be something where I might just have to shorten the name. I've tried making the font smaller for all the names as well and for some reason that didn't work either.

Comment: Wow I fixed it. I am using wordpress Elementor and I just selected yes for "stretch selection." Hours... wasted.. lol